# Determining observations with same values in one variable

Tags: r

My problem is that i want to determine households which have the same and then use the rank number (ranked by income) to create another rank variable.[Sample.Data.Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1pAP.png)

For example you have a data.frame like displayed in the image. The first 2 observations have no income. So there are 2(=n) observations with the same income and rank of 1(=y) and 2(=x). The new rank variable I want to create for both observations: rank.new = (y+x)/n. So that there new column with "rank.new" where in observation 1 and 2 the value is 1.5.

Of course I have many more observations an more identical income households, so i want to ask you have i could fix this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the function `rank`

```
Income = c(0,0,150,300,300,440,500,500,500)
rank(Income)
[1] 1.5 1.5 3.0 4.5 4.5 6.0 8.0 8.0 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making your test data a little bigger to show what happens when there are more than two points that are the same group.  You just need to group the points that have the same income and take the average of the groups. I am assuming that the data has been sorted by Income.

```
## Test Data
Income = c(0,0,150,300,300,440,500,500,500)
Rank   = 1:length(Income)

Group = cumsum(c(1, diff(Income) != 0))
NewRank = aggregate(Rank, list(Group), mean)[Group,2]
NewRank
[1] 1.5 1.5 3.0 4.5 4.5 6.0 8.0 8.0 8.0
```